# How to automate creation of client secret json file

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django-templates, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I am looking to integrate the google analytics in html page by clicking the **login button**, by clicking the login button how to get client_secret.json automatically.
Please help me
Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

The client_secret.json file is used for authenticating an application to Google via OAuth2.  The credentials file is created on [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/) when you create your client credentials for your project.  This must be configured manually by the developer of the application.

This can not be fetched automatically.

Comment: Not possible to fetch automatically by giving the login credential of google analytics?

Comment: You want to download the  client_secret.json automatically correct?  That needs to be created on Google developer console and has nothing to do with Google Analytics api other then having the file will give you the ablity to request Google analytics data but to do that you need to manually create the  client_secret.json file.

Comment: yes, i want download the client_secret.json file automatically is it possible?

Comment: As stated in my answer No its not.  This file can not be fetched automatically.  You need to go to google developer console and set up your client credentials and down the file manually.      Then you can follow something like  [Python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-py) to request data from Google analytics.

Comment: Welcome to stack. remember to accept the answer if it helped you.